# Athena query to find how many users from one month are in other months

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, timestamp, presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to get recurrent users. My date is in S3 bucket and I'm using Amazon Athena to query it.

I'm interest to see how many users from September(9) are in October (10) and in November (11) ...etc

This is my query to get this data:

I would like to have something like this at the end:
[recurrentusers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmnXV.png)

Comment: What do your desired results look like?

Comment: like in the link in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is how my table after query looks like:

I understand you have a table like `active_users (month varchar, userid varchar)`, or you have a way to produce intermediate result like this.

> I'm interest to see how many users from September(9) are in October (10) and in November (11) ...etc

You can achieve the desired with:

```
SELECT month, count(*)
FROM active_users
WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid FROM active_users WHERE month = '2019-09')
```

Comment: thank you can you please check out query to see how to optimize it to be faster now it takes 2 min

Comment: I don't know how to get useful runtime insights from Athena, so it's hard to optimize a query there. I would recommend spinning up a Presto cluster (very easy eg using Starburst's https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/) and then using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Of course, interpreting the results isn't easy (and seems to be beyond SO's question-answer scheme), so I invite you to join the Presto community slack: https://prestosql.io/slack.html.